# Bootstrapping clusters in R

Tags: r, bootstrap, clustered-standard-errors

I am running a negative binomial regression of clinic counts in each county in the entire country (~3k counties).  I'd like to at least partially account for the non-independence of neighboring counties by bootstrapping the confidence intervals in a "clustered" fashion--e.g. draw an entire state's (50 states total) worth of data at once.  This has become [standard practice](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/rest.90.3.414#.Vg7SjnUVhBc), for better or for worse, in the econometric literature.

I could write the code to do this myself, but the `boot` package seems like it should have the ability to do this somehow, and in general I prefer tested, general solutions to one-off hacks.  Is there a way to coerce the `boot` package to do a clustered bootstrap?

I tried the `strata` argument, but that randomizes *within* strata rather than randomizing which cluster gets taken, as the following code confirms:

```
dat <- data.frame( cluster=rep(letters[1:5],each=10), x=runif(5*10), stringsAsFactors=TRUE )
boot.stat <- function(dat,idx) {
    print(dat[idx,]$cluster)
     print(table(dat[idx,]$cluster))
    mean(dat[idx,]$x)
    }
    boot( 
     data=dat, 
     statistic=boot.stat, 
     strata=dat$cluster, 
    stype="i", 
    R=5 
)
```

Comment: Why would an unconditional bootstrap be inappropriate for your purposes? It would generate a random number of observations from each cluster and there would be no permutation of cluster labels from bootstrap samples.

Comment: @AdamO Because it destroys the *within-cluster* correlation.  Maintaining that correlation is the logic behind sampling the entire cluster.

Comment: Does it? If values were constant within each cluster, they would still be constant within each cluster for any unconditional bootstrap resampling of the data. I think it would maintain cluster level correlation. That wouldn't be the case with permutation testing, of course.

Comment: @AdamO I think it does but I have been crazy recently.  I'll try to come up with a simulation demonstrating soon, but regardless it's the method I'd like to replicate.

Comment: @AdamO if I'm not mistaken it's the same logic behind time series bootstraps--drawing blocks to account for serial correlation. And Ari, that link is dead, do you by any chance recall the paper you had linked? I could go for some academic references on this topic.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Not sure which one I meant to link to, but Cameron Gelbach Miller probably.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman I seem to have forgotten about this conversation. For unconditional bootstrap, you would need to have a variable indicating cluster membership which is jointly sampled with the rest of the observations in the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to estimate a statistic per state and that average that statistic to get a bootstrapped estimation of the overall statistic.

[Stratified sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling) does something different. It ensures that the label is samples representatively in each sample. I do not think that is what you want to do.

You could do this manually without being *hacky*. Using the `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `purrr` package from the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) this becomes transparant and clean code.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat <- data.frame(cluster=rep(letters[1:5],each=10),
  x=runif(5*10), stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

boot.stat2 <- function(df) {
  mean(df$x)
}

dat %>%
  nest(x) %>%
  mutate(stat = map_dbl(data, boot.stat2))
```

More information on the

- [pipe](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) `%>%` using dplyr
- [nesting and unnesting](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html) using tidyr
- [mapping values](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr) using purrr